# Get battery temperature using androidhelper

Tags: qpython

I am wondering how to get battery temperature using

```
batteryGetTemperature()
```

Why do get error
And how to solve it

```
droid.batteryStartMonitoring()
        print("Battery Percentage: " + str(droid.batteryGetLevel().result) + "%")
        print("Battery Temperature: " + str(int(droid.batteryGetTemperature().result)/int(10)) + "°C")
        droid.batteryStopMonitoring()
```

Answer (score 0):

Those batteryGet… functions return None now.
I don't know why. It seems to work before.

Here's a working script I wrote long ago:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:console
from androidhelper import sl4a
droid=sl4a.Android()
droid.batteryStartMonitoring()
raw_input("\nBattery Data\nPress to continue…")
try:
    data=droid.readBatteryData()
    if data.error==None:
        print "Data:"
        for x in ["temperature","level","status","plugged","voltage","health","technology","battery_present"]:
            print " "+x+":",data.result[x]
    else:
        print "ERROR!"
        print data.error
except Exception as err:
    print "ERROR!"
    print err
finally:
    droid.batteryStopMonitoring()
"""
ex.(id=0,result={"":""},error=None)
BatteryManagerFacade
batteryCheckPresent
 ex.True
batteryGetHealth
 1 - unknown;
 2 - good;
 3 - overheat;
 4 - dead;
 5 - over voltage;
 6 - unspecified failure;
batteryGetLevel
 %
batteryGetPlugType
 -1 - unknown
 0 - unplugged;
 1 - power source is an AC charger
 2 - power source is a USB port
batteryGetStatus
 1 - unknown;
 2 - charging;
 3 - discharging;
 4 - not charging;
 5 - full;
batteryGetTechnology
 ex.Li-ion
batteryGetTemperature
 ex.310
batteryGetVoltage
 ex.4248
batteryStartMonitoring
 None
batteryStopMonitoring
 None
readBatteryData
 status
 temperature
 level
 battery_present
 plugged
 health
 voltage
 technology
"""
```